# Creating function that returns array of function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, console.log

I need to create a function that return an array that consists of n keys 0..[n-1]. The value of each key is a function that upon calling prints the key via (console.log()). e.g. fun8(5)[3] prints 3.

I tried this:

```
function fun8(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = function() {
            console.log(i);
        };
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And it doesn't work. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Note that i is global here. This can lead to many bugs.

Comment: `fun8(5)[3]` wouldn't be invoking anything - I think you mean `fun8(5)[3]()`

Comment: This is kind of my first experience in JS. What would you do different? Thanks